# GetSlotBufferLocked while trying to play android mp3 media

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to make a soundboard app and it works for the first few mp3s played, but afterwards I get the following error:
"MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released." Am I releasing the audio correctly? (look at last function). Thanks. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridview;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.rich1);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.no_youre_finished);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.mexico);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.thank_you_darling);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.youll_get_bored_with_winning);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.i_just_sold_);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.amazingvictory);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bequiet);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bequietandjusthitthem);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bernysanders);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.buildinghotel);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.buildmilitary);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.canigoalong);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.china);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.countrygoingtohell);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.enough);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ever);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.fivehundredbillion);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 18:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.fordismovingtomexico);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 19:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.fortyninepercent);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 20:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.friendsleavinggermany);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;

                    case 21:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.gethimout);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 22:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.getoutandvote);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 23:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.heardofivanka);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 24:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.heresapoll);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 25:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.hewasverynasty);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 26:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.iamselffunding);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 27:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.idontknowmaybesomethingelse);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 28:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ifwereattackedjapan);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 29:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ihavealotoffriendschina);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;

                    case 30:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ilovepolice);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 31:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.iloveyou);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 32:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.iorderfourthousand);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 33:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.isntittrue);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 34:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.largestdrugbuyer);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 35:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.legally);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 36:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.letsdoit);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 37:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.listentothis);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    case 38:
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.lookatthosenumbers);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }



            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was releasing the media player before the switch statement:

```
// Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
```